# Booting Arch Linux sticks with "Reading supported feature failed (-16)"

Tags: linux, bluetooth, boot

My new [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) installation always sticks after rebooting with the message

> [x.yz] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16).

It is just doing nothing until I start a session on tty2 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and going back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> without logging in in tty2 (btw. I have installed [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) with [GDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager)). Bluetooth is working well once I'm logged in...

Here are all `journalctl - b` outputs containing 'Bluetooth':

```
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook bluetoothd[392]: Bluetooth daemon 5.56
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Mar 06 14:56:23 archBook bluetoothd[392]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized
Mar 06 14:56:25 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Mar 06 14:56:25 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1675919 usecs
Mar 06 14:56:25 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
Mar 06 14:56:25 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11722 usecs
Mar 06 14:56:25 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
Mar 06 14:56:25 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
Mar 06 14:56:25 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
Mar 06 14:56:25 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Telemetry exception format not supported
Mar 06 14:56:25 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 50 week 12 2019
Mar 06 15:01:32 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Mar 06 15:01:32 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Mar 06 15:01:32 archBook kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Mar 06 15:01:36 archBook systemd[749]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
Mar 06 15:01:36 archBook systemd[749]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
```

How can I fix this? It sucks to always enter tty2 before I can log in via GUI...

Comment: In my case I had previously put an apparently invalid file into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and removing that file worked. The output was probably not an actually relevant error in my case, it just happened to be the last output before X read the configuration file, failed at that and printed no errors at all. So if you still have that problem now, try checking other things that are not Bluetooth related.